# In hybris how to show errors on storefront?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I am a beginner in hybris.I have a requirement to develop B2C website which performs buyers address validations.I am using b2c accelerator and I can successfully apply validations on constraints.I am able to test the same in cockpits but on a storefront, i am getting server error for wrong inputs and exception on a console gets generated for same successfully.so how to show those errors on storefront?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to frame questions properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can do this using utils class called:

```
de.hybris.platform.acceleratorstorefrontcommons.controllers.util.GlobalMessages
```

You can use methods of the GlobalMessages class depending on the message type you want to display. For example you can display error message when form has validation errors:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some-url, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String someUrl( BindingResult bindingResult, final Model model, SomeForm form)
{
    getSomeValidator().validate(form, bindingResult);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
        GlobalMessages.addErrorMessage(model, "form.global.error");
        return "errorPage";
    } else {
        return "successPage";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to nikita_pavlenko, I will figure it out with the given references.

Comment: can we do it through any cockpit/extension without changing the code?

Comment: @suyog_sk  unfortunately this is code-driven error message, so you can't do that via cockpit/configuration.